# why doesn't the line refresh?

Tags: java, android, handler

LineRefresh.java:

```
package LineRefresh.xyz.com;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LineRefresh extends Activity {
DrawView drawView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawView);

}
}
```

DrawView.java:

```
package LineRefresh.xyz.com;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
public void onDraw( final Canvas canvas) { 
 paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
 canvas.drawLine(50, 200, 270, 200, paint);  
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {      
         paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      canvas.drawLine(50, 200, 270, 200, paint); 
      handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
     }
    };                 
}

}
```

Comment: offtopic: packages are usually named like com.company.product.application.class, not in revert prder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `invalidate();` inside your view in order for the OnDraw method to be called again. The onDraw should look something like this:

```
public void onDraw( final Canvas canvas) { 
 paint.setColor(color);
 canvas.drawLine(50, 200, 270, 200, paint);                
}
```

Also, don't place the creation of the handler and runnable inside the onDraw method. The onDraw method will be called numerous times, whenever is needed and you don't want to create as many runnables.

In your constructor:

```
color = Color.Black;    
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
  // change color
  color = color == Color.Red ? Color.Black : Color.Red;      
  invalidate(); 
  handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
 }
}; 
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); // You need this to call the handler for the first time
```

Comment: I've tried this...but the line doesn't blink...as in, it doesn't refresh on the screen

Comment: See my edited code. The line should change colors every second. Also, try to debug the code to see what is happening. The onDraw method should be called once a second, every time invalidate is called.